# Flex encode string according to RFC RFC 2396

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, encode, rfc2396

How can I encode a string according to RFC 2396, using Actionscript/Flex 3?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Javascript, in Actionscript you can use the following top level (or global) functions to encode/decode URI's:

[`encodeUri()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#encodeURI%28%29)
[`encodeURIComponent()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#encodeURIComponent%28%29)
[`decodeURI()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#decodeURI%28%29)
 and [`decodeURIComponent()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#decodeURIComponent%28%29)

As well as:

[`escape()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#escape%28%29) [`unescape()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#unescape%28%29)

There are subtle differences between these 6 global functions, check the links to the docs above. Here's an article that [discusses the difference](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm) in Javascript, but it should be the same for Actionscript.